# jQuery Slide + events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a page that will present the user with a content slider, so that the user can click 'next' to browse through the slides.

However, I also want to hide any 'previous' buttons/links and additionally, when the user reaches the last slide in the list the 'next' button needs to be replaced with a different button and take the user to another page on the site instead of going back to the beginning of the slides.

I wondered if anyone had any advice on how to code this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your slides are images, you have this done in Lightbox (at least for the first part of your need):

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

You might also be interested in the following script (based on Scriptacolous):

http://railspikes.com/2007/5/14/slider-js-a-javascript-slider-component

Also this is a possibility:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/anythingslider-a-great-jquery-slider-plugin/